# Zookeeper conflict in Hbase and Storm

Tags: hbase, bigdata, apache-storm, apache-zookeeper

Hi I am going to explain my problem. Please read throughly and then comment/answer.

I installed Hbase0.98-hadoop2 on my machine(Ubuntu 12). At that time I did not installed zookeeper. 
But yesterday I installed storm on my machine. But for this purpose I have to install zookeeper as well. So I installed zookeeper as well.

Now if I run Hbase it works fine. Then when I run storm it also works fine.

But when I run both Hbase and storm in parallel then it create problems for me.

**Use case 1:**

```
1- Start Hbase
2- Start storm(starting nimbus,supervisor,ui,then localhost:8772 on web browser)
Everything works good. (Notice I did not started zookeeper in this usecase)
```

**Use case 2:**

```
1- Start zookeeper
2- Start storm(starting nimbus,supervisor,ui,then localhost:8772 on web browser)
3- Start Hbase
Now storm works good. But when I do any thing on Hbase shell it stucks for 5 minutes or more and then give error.
```

**Use case 3:**

```
1- Start Storm(starting nimbus,supervisor,ui,then localhost:8772 on web browser)
Notice I did not started zookeeper in this case. Now storm will give error on browser.
```

**Use case 4:**

```
1- Start Hbase
It works good. Even I did not run zookeeper.
```

Now I know there is some problem with zookeeper. Hbase have its own zookeeper and for storm I have installed an other one. So they are conflicting each other.

So how can I get rid of this problem?

PLUS: If you want to see the errors then I will show them. But I think it's clear that problem is due to zookeeper.

Comment: Was your problem resolved? Can you share the HBase logs for usecase-2?

Comment: Also you can use common zookeeper for both HBase and Storm, you only need to change "export HBASE_MANAGES_ZK=false" in conf/hbase-env.sh